# Confidence Intervals

Tags: python, scipy, statistics

I am doing statistical analysis and need confidence intervals, I am assuming normally distributed values and thus using the T distribution for intervals.

The solutions I found are using either `scipy.stats.sem( data )` or `ss.t.fit( data, len(data)-1 )` as source for the `scale`-parameter. Full example:

```
import numpy as np, scipy.stats as ss

# sample size
sample = 30

# data generate
dist = ss.norm( loc=100, scale=20 )
data = dist.rvs( size=sample )

# degrees of freedom
df = len(data)-1

# Using sem
loc, scale = np.mean(data), ss.sem(data)
print( ss.t.ppf(0.95, df=df, scale=scale) )

# Using fit
params = ss.t.fit( data, df )
loc, scale = params[-2], params[-1]
print( ss.t.ppf(0.95, df=df, scale=scale) )
```

I expected both solutions to work, the former just being more efficient. However, the output looks like:

```
6.56521148383
25.8184505101
```

What is the difference?

If I plot the original `dist` vs the distribution with the params from `ss.t.fit`, it looks right.

Comment: Your scale parameter is 3.84 in the first case and 20.7 in the second, differing by a factor of `sqrt(df)`. I think you've just mixed up the correction factors, since the scale of the t-dist is multiplied by `sqrt(df)` usually.

Comment: To add to bnaecker's comment: In the first case it uses the distribution of the mean, in the second case it uses the distribution of a t-distributed observation.